# Opencart csv import issue from shopify

Tags: php, csv, opencart, shopify

I have downloaded shopify product csv file now i want to import product using that csv in opencart but unable to import that csv. please help to import in opencart.

Comment: 'unable to import that csv' - Please explain the method you've tried and errors shown.

Comment: this is link i have used for : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/321-installing-the-bulk-importexport-extension-for-opencart-products                                error is undefined offset

Comment: What about the errors shown? Did you check the error logs? If you're using a third party extension, then please contact the extension developer. Also read the extension documentation.

Comment: Undefined offset: 3 in products_importer.php on line 306   Undefined offset: 4 in products_importer.php on line 307

Comment: These errors are from the third party extension files, right? Please contact the extension developer.

Comment: if you have any method to import products from shopify to opencart than suggest me. i will follow it. thanks

Comment: I think the CSV templates for Shopify and Open Cart are different. Try converting it into Open Cart recognisable template and try.